# how to provide xsl lib to saxon by command line?

Tags: xslt, jar, saxon

I'm using the jar saxon9he.jar to create some xsl files. This is the command line that I'm using.

```
java -jar saxon9he.jar -o:output.xml -s:input.xml -xsl:mystylesheet.xslt
```

mystylesheet.xslt has this line inside it:

```
<xsl:import href="datetime_lib.xsl"/>
```

How can I provide this extra xsl file to the jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mention this extra stylesheet module on the command line. The URI `datetime_lib.xsl` is interpreted as a relative URI, and is taken as relative to the base URI of the containing stylesheet module mystylesheet.xslt. In practice that means everything works nicely if the two modules are in the same directory (and if not, you can use a relative location like `href="../lib/other.xsl"`).

If you want to resolve datetime_lib.xsl in some other way (perhaps it's somewhere completely unrelated), then the normal way to achieve this is by use of a catalog resolver. In recent releases of Saxon you can use the option -catalog:catalog.xml to point to a catalog, which is an XML document in a particular format that redirects URIs to a different location. You can read more about using catalogs with Saxon here:

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!sourcedocs/xml-catalogs

and the catalog format is described here:

http://xerces.apache.org/xml-commons/components/resolver/resolver-article.html